# Display image in php

Tags: php, image

how to display image in html by retrieving it from mysql database.

i have the following code but only text is being displayed in place of image.
How to display the image instead of the text of image.

Code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    //echo "<div>";
    //echo "<div class=\"slide-image\">";
    print $row['Image'];
    //echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"slide-text\">";
    echo $row['Head'];
    echo $row['Description'];
    //echo "</div>";
    //echo "</div>";
}
```

It displays the resulting JPEG as text, which as you might imagine is very difficult to interpret.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to save the image as a location instead of actual image? Plus I don't believe the answers below are feasible because you have html and text so a header wouldn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the `Content-Type` header with PHP.  If it is JPEG it will be `image/jpeg`.  You can set it with:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Be sure to set that header before outputting any data.

### update

But in your file as you are outputting image data and text data from same document you cant set its header type as multiple types.

one option would be

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<div>";
    echo "<div class=\"slide-image\">";
    echo "<img src='image_render.php?id=".$row['some_key_for_record']."'";
    //print $row['Image']; we are moving it to an external page
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"slide-text\">";
    echo $row['Head'];
    echo $row['Description'];
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

and in image_render.php

```
 //code to pull data from db according to $_GET['id'];
 header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
 print $row['Image'];
 //no text data to be output from here
```

Comment: what should i put in place of some_key_for_record. In my image data base i have kept only 3 columns Image, Head, Description. can u please provide me with the exact code.

Comment: @YogeshJadhav : it can be the primary key for the image record so that at `image_render.php` you can pull data and render image.

Answer (score 1):

If you are stroing the image source(full path) in your `MYSQL table` then you can able to print the `html img` tag inside your php like a html `div`. You can do it by this way,

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        //echo "<div>";
        //echo "<div class=\"slide-image\">";
        echo '<img src='".$row['Image']."' width="100" height="100" />';
        //echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"slide-text\">";
        echo $row['Head'];
        echo $row['Description'];
        //echo "</div>";
        //echo "</div>";
    }
```

**Note :** 
If you want only the image to be displayed in your web page then you can do it with `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`